# wxPython FileDialog crash in mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython

I have the following code:

```
import wx
from sys import platform

wildcard = "CSV files|*.csv|"\
           "XML files|*.xml|"\
           "Microsoft Excel files|*.xlsx" if platform == "win32" else "CSV files|*.csv|"\
                                                                      "XML files|*.xml|"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            frame_1, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir="",
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard, #PROBLEM IS HERE THAT'S FOR SURE
            style=wx.OPEN
    )
    dlg.ShowModal() #IT CRASHES HERE
    dlg.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This FileDialog works perfect in Windows and Linux but crashes in Mac OS X. Is there anything I could change in order to get FileDialog working properly in Mac OS X?

Python 2.7.3, wxPython 2.8, Mac OS X 10.6

**UPDATE: Updated to be a small sample.**

**UPDATE 2: Without "wildcard" parameter it works great but I need wildcard anyway.**

Comment: Do you have a fully runnable example? I chucked this into a `wx.Frame` and it works ok for me (I'm also on Python 2.7.3, wxPython 2.8, Mac OS X 10.6)

Comment: Fully runnable example is here: https://bitbucket.org/fire_lizard/aproxim/src/6c2374d695517d1a7d991166d949b6146540ebeb/app_window.py?at=default (method btnOpen_Click or btnSave_Click)

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to make a small sample? http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Comment: Sorry for a big delay just managed to make small sample to reproduce the error. My post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found answer myself:

http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4489

It crashes in Mac when wildcard improperly formatted, after removing last "|" in wildcard everything work just fine.